# Amazon Cognito javascript sdk listrecords invalid security token

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to learn how to work with nodejs and amazon cognito. Instead of using google, facebook, etc I am using a developer authenticated identity. I've got that part working and can see the identity being created in cognito. When I try to run listRecords though it doesn't work. I want to just add a user's name to a dataset to see that it works. It is giving me the error below here. I'm not quite sure what it means by security token because the developer access and secret keys are working fine for getting an identityId out of cognito.

```
undefinedUnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid. UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

The code I'm using is below here. The error is occurring on listRecords and it is not executing the error function. It fails on the call to listRecords from what I can tell. I've double checked the access keys as well.

```
// initialize the Credentials object
            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentity(params);

            AWS.config.credentials.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) console.log("## credentials.get: ".red + err, err.stack);
                else {

                    AWS.config.credentials.identityId = data.IdentityId;
                    console.log(data);
                    var cognitosync = new AWS.CognitoSync();
                    cognitosync.listRecords({
                        DatasetName: "userData",
                        IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId,
                        IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL,
                    }, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) console.log("## listRecords: ".red + err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                        else {
                            console.log("This is the sync session token: " + data.SyncSessionToken);

                            //Parameters for updating the dataset
                            var params = {
                                DatasetName: "userData",
                                IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId,
                                IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL,
                                RecordPatches: [{
                                    Key: 'UserName',
                                    Op: 'replace',
                                    SyncCount: data.DatasetSyncCount,
                                    Value: 'FirstName' //this needs to be tied into first and last name
                                }]
                            };

                            //Make the call to Amazon Cognito
                            cognitosync.updateRecords(params, function (err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log("## updateRecords: ".red + err, err.stack);
                                } // an error occurred
                                else {
                                    var dataRecords = JSON.stringify(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    });

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This documentation may be helpful for you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/

In general

(1) You are going to want to use get the openIdToken first using AWS.CognitoIdentity to call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.

This is described in the "Getting a Token (Server Side)" section in the above documentation.

(2) Once you have the token from above, you set the AWS.config.credentials as so:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
   IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
   IdentityId: 'IDENTITY_ID_RETURNED_FROM_YOUR_PROVIDER',
   Logins: {
      'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': 'TOKEN_RETURNED_FROM_YOUR_PROVIDER'
   }
});
```

You should then be able to make calls using the user's credentials.